# distinct select query with zero to many join

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have the sql query below.  The query has been working for serveral years without the `contacttags` join, but now we need add the `contacttags` join which is zero to many.  The query below without the `contacttags` join would return zero results.  Now that we have the `contacttags` join, it returns one row with all null values.  What is the correct way to query when a join can have zero to many.

```
SELECT `contacts`.`id`, `contacts`.`nameFirst`, `contacts`.`nameLast`, `contacts`.`nameBusiness`,
`e1`.`nameShort` AS `ownerEmployee`, `c2`.`formattedName` AS `ownerEmployeeName`,
`e2`.`id` AS `employeeId`, `e2`.`nameShort` AS `employeeNameShort`,
`v1`.`id` AS `vendorId`,
GROUP_CONCAT(`ct`.`id`) AS `contactTags`
FROM `contacts`
# employee assigned to contact - one to one
LEFT JOIN `employees` AS `e1` ON `e1`.`id` = `contacts`.`ownerEmployeeId` AND `e1`.`tenantId` = `contacts`.`tenantId`
LEFT JOIN `contacts` AS `c2` ON `c2`.`id` = `e1`.`contactId` AND `c2`.`tenantId` = `e1`.`tenantId`
# if contact is employee - zero or one
LEFT JOIN `employees` AS `e2` ON `e2`.`tenantId` = `contacts`.`tenantId` AND `e2`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL AND `e2`.`contactId` = `contacts`.`id`
# if contact is vendor - zero or one
LEFT JOIN `vendors` AS `v1` ON `v1`.`tenantId` = `contacts`.`tenantId` AND `v1`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL AND `v1`.`contactId` = `contacts`.`id` AND `v1`.`vendorStatus` = "Active"
# tags assigned to contact, zero to many
LEFT JOIN `contacttags` AS `ct` ON `ct`.`tenantId` = `contacts`.`tenantId` AND `ct`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL AND `ct`.`contactId` = `contacts`.`id`
WHERE `contacts`.`tenantId` = 3 AND `contacts`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL
 AND `contacts`.`contactStatus` in ("Active","Working") AND `e1`.`employeeStatus` != "Active"
ORDER BY `contacts`.`formattedName` ASC;
```

This query is used for many scenarios with changing the where clause for what needs to be displayed.  With adding `contacttags` join, we need to include the option to search by tag assigned. Below is the same query the where clause changed to filter by tag.  The query should return zero results, but it is returning one result will all null values.

```
SELECT `contacts`.`id`, `contacts`.`nameFirst`, `contacts`.`nameLast`, `contacts`.`nameBusiness`,
`e1`.`nameShort` AS `ownerEmployee`, `c2`.`formattedName` AS `ownerEmployeeName`,
`e2`.`id` AS `employeeId`, `e2`.`nameShort` AS `employeeNameShort`,
`v1`.`id` AS `vendorId`,
GROUP_CONCAT(`ct`.`id`) AS `contactTags`
FROM `contacts`
# employee assigned to contact - one to one
LEFT JOIN `employees` AS `e1` ON `e1`.`id` = `contacts`.`ownerEmployeeId` AND `e1`.`tenantId` = `contacts`.`tenantId`
LEFT JOIN `contacts` AS `c2` ON `c2`.`id` = `e1`.`contactId` AND `c2`.`tenantId` = `e1`.`tenantId`
# if contact is employee - zero or one
LEFT JOIN `employees` AS `e2` ON `e2`.`tenantId` = `contacts`.`tenantId` AND `e2`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL AND `e2`.`contactId` = `contacts`.`id`
# if contact is vendor - zero or one
LEFT JOIN `vendors` AS `v1` ON `v1`.`tenantId` = `contacts`.`tenantId` AND `v1`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL AND `v1`.`contactId` = `contacts`.`id` AND `v1`.`vendorStatus` = "Active"
# tags assigned to contact, zero to many
LEFT JOIN `contacttags` AS `ct` ON `ct`.`tenantId` = `contacts`.`tenantId` AND `ct`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL AND `ct`.`contactId` = `contacts`.`id`
WHERE `contacts`.`tenantId` = 3 AND `contacts`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL
 AND `contacts`.`contactStatus` in ("Active","Working") AND `ct`.`tagId`=999
ORDER BY `contacts`.`formattedName` ASC;
```

Comment: That entirely depends on the result you want to see. A query can't return what isn't there so it just depends on how you want to represent that absence.

Comment: `AND `e1`.`employeeStatus` != "Active"` -- That's not a left join anymore, but an inner join.

Comment: How do you get a GROUP_CONCAT if you are not using GROUP BY?

Comment: A left join will handle a zero to man relationship, but why you get one row, when you expect no row, isn't something I can ascertain from looking at only your queries. What did that one row contain?

Comment: In the question title you refer to distinct - but that isn't contained in your queries.  Are you also trying to avoid the contacttags join from multiplying the rows returned (and is that why you have used `group_concat`)?

Comment: I don't understand why you reach back into `employees` and `contacts` a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to use your "general purpose" query that you tack filters onto, then you can avoid directly joining the contacttag table - instead use an `and exists` predicate in the where clause. The big advantage of this is that it won't have any row multiplication effect on the existing query e.g:

```
SELECT
      contacts.id
    , contacts.nameFirst
    , contacts.nameLast
    , contacts.nameBusiness
    , e1.nameShort AS ownerEmployee
    , c2.formattedName AS ownerEmployeeName
    , e2.id AS employeeId
    , e2.nameShort AS employeeNameShort
    , v1.id AS vendorId
FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN employees AS e1 ON e1.id = contacts.ownerEmployeeId
    AND e1.tenantId = contacts.tenantId
LEFT JOIN contacts AS c2 ON c2.id = e1.contactId
    AND c2.tenantId = e1.tenantId
LEFT JOIN employees AS e2 ON e2.tenantId = contacts.tenantId
    AND e2.dateDeleted IS NULL
    AND e2.contactId = contacts.id
LEFT JOIN vendors AS v1 ON v1.tenantId = contacts.tenantId
    AND v1.dateDeleted IS NULL
    AND v1.contactId = contacts.id
    AND v1.vendorStatus = 'Active'
WHERE contacts.tenantId = 3
    AND contacts.dateDeleted IS NULL
    AND contacts.contactStatus IN ('Active', 'Working')
    -- filter by contacttag.tagid without any row multiplication
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM contacttags AS ct
        WHERE ct.tenantId = contacts.tenantId
        AND ct.dateDeleted IS NULL
        AND ct.contactId = contacts.id
        AND ct.tagId = 999
        )
ORDER BY contacts.formattedName ASC;
```

**nb** for the query within the `exists (select ...)` you may use `select null` or `select 1` or `select *`, it is the where clause of this query that determines true or false so the select clause here does not really matter.